# VB.NET DataGridView -> Add a column and fill cells with data from another cell

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I have a DataGridView which I fill in the following way:

```
Function updategrid(ByVal CurrentBroker, ByVal CurrentPallet)
    Dim i = 0
    Dim SQLText As String
    SQLText = "SELECT " & _
    "invoer.idInvoer," & _
    "invoer.BRKNo as Broker," & _
    "invoer.Palletno as Pallet," & _
    "invoer.Tabblad AS ValTabblad," & _
    "Tabblad.TabbladType, " & _
    "invoer.Hardwaretype as Hardwaretype," & _
    "invoer.Fabrikant AS Fabrikant," & _
    "invoer.Model As Model, " & _
    "invoer.Serienummer, " & _
    "invoer.AssetTag, " & _
    "invoer.Schade, " & _
    "invoer.Opmerkingen, " & _
    "Tabblad.idTabblad, " & _
    "invoer.details, " & _
    "invoer.aantal, " & _
    "invoer.RegisterDate " & _
    "FROM Invoer as invoer " & _
    "INNER JOIN Tabblad as Tabblad ON invoer.Tabblad = tabblad.idTabblad " & _
    "WHERE invoer.BRKNo = '" & CurrentBroker & "'" & _
    "AND invoer.PalletNo = " & CurrentPallet & "  " & _
    "ORDER BY invoer.RegisterDate DESC"

    ds.Tables.Clear()
    Try
        Data = New DataTable
        dataAdap = New MySqlDataAdapter(SQLText, dbconn)

        cmdBuilder = New MySqlCommandBuilder(dataAdap)
        dataAdap.Fill(ds, "Overzicht")
        With DGVOverzicht
            .DataSource = ds.Tables("Overzicht")
            .ColumnHeadersVisible = True
            .AutoGenerateColumns = True
            .Visible = True

            For i = 0 To .ColumnCount - 1 Step 1
                Select Case .Columns(i).HeaderText
                    Case "ValTabblad" : .Columns(i).Visible = False
                    Case "details"
                        ' hide the ID's, display text..
                        .Columns(i).Visible = False
                    Case "idTabblad" : .Columns(i).Visible = False
                    Case "idHWModel" : .Columns(i).Visible = False
                    Case "idHardware" : .Columns(i).Visible = False
                    Case "idInvoer" : .Columns(i).Visible = False
                End Select
            Next
        End With
        Return True
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Return False
    End Try

    Return 1
End Function
```

This works like a charm, but I need to add a column next to the column which I hide: Details.
The Column Details holds the ID's of all details selected in the record (e.g. 1;5;2;19;20;100)
I want to give the user a bit more information about the actual selected details, e.g. by do a lookup in MySQL to see what details those ID's actually are..

However, I was told not to do a inner join on a comma separated list in MySQL due to the fact that it would be 'slow as frozen snail'.. 
So the next thing I can think of is filling the DGV with all the information from the Database, hide the ID column and 'find and replace' the values in another cell, and thus looking it up in MySQL..

If anyone could point me into some kind of direction in this, I'd be very grateful.. since I'm staring at the code for over a few hours now, and not a single lightbulbs seems to pop up :)

Thank in advance!

Comment: since the user will have to tell which details they want to look at (say by clicking a column), you should be able to create a new query using the ID for the row, the contents of the column and the item represented by the cell.  Alternatively, and cruder, would be to split and parse your Details column and create a query from that - it appears you will still need to get the DGV cell to know which pair of Details info to use.

Comment: the user will already have filled in the details, yet I want to display them in the DGVoverzicht, instead of the idDetails's (0;1;2;3) I want to display the idShortCode's (DOA;BOA;DNU;SNO) etc.. I store the details by index so that the short code's can change over time, but the definition does not. 

I do like to know how to use the results of the split on the details column and display it into another (yet to create) column.. 

So the sequence must be:
Load database --> Split DetailsID Column, Query DBase for definition --> Create Column with definitions in Comma Separated Format --> done

Comment: I follow about 10% of that, since I dont have the piece specs.  Rather than collapsing the data for distinct IDs into a string (e.g. 1;5;2;19;20;100), save them as other hidden columns (ThisDetailID, ThatDetailID, FooDetailID).  Now when you need certain details you have a clean starting point.

Comment: The app I'm creating is a registration app. The user fills in a form and defines certain aspects of a device in there. E.g. Serialnumber and Details about the device. The Details are a list of predefined codes that the user can select. As soon as the user is done filling in the form, the data gets saved into the dbase and the DGVOverzicht (just a DGV that displays all the data already put into the database) refreshes. In this DGV, the data in the database is shown,  so that the user can select a row, and edit the data. Since the Details are inserted by ID, the idDetails column does show the...

Comment: ...idDetails column, in a comma separated list (e.g. 0;1;5;8).
Instead of this list, I want the actual codes of those details to be shown in another column (which isn't part op the actual Dbase, but just for readability). That's why I have to split the value in the idDetails Column, and display them into another column, with the codes which have to be searched into the dabase..

Hope that does make more sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

Well, i think I kind of did it finally.
What I did was select an extra column in the SQLstatemenr (invoer.idInvoer AS details_explain) so that I have an extra column to play with and at the position where I want it.
Then i added the following code to change the content of that column:

```
    ' replace ID's in Details_Explain with ShortCodes from DGV

    For row = 0 To DGVOverzicht.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim strDetailsExplain = ""
        Dim DetailIDs As Array
        DetailIDs = Split(DGVOverzicht.Rows(row).Cells("details").Value.ToString, ";")
        For Each item In DetailIDs
            If Not item = Nothing Then
                strDetailsExplain = strDetailsExplain & DGV.Rows(Int(item)).Cells("DetailsCode").Value & ":"
            End If
        Next

        DGVOverzicht.Rows(row).Cells("Details_Explain").Value = strDetailsExplain
    Next
```

I suppose this is not the most clean way to do it, but it will have to do, since I don't know a better way of doing it..

Comment: tiny change.. I suddenly received 'default DGV Error messages' stating that my string is not a valid Int32.. (duh..)

I changed the SQL Statement to not select an int32 value item, but a string item.. which made it work again :)